# Can we add [problem] to the tag blacklist?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist

Earlier today we had a number of questions tagged [problem](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem)

I cleaned them all up, but can we add it to the tag blacklist to avoid it's return?

Comment: Seems like the very definition of a meta tag.

Comment: @AlEverett I think he means on the main site; its not very useful there.

Comment: @JustinY: Yes, I know exactly what he meant. By "meta tag" I'm not talking about tags used on the meta site.

Comment: About [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been done.

Also [problems](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problems)